# Grothendieck's manuscript on differential manifolds

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I have a Japanese book on Grothendieck's life and his mathematical works.
The author writes that Grothendieck wrote manuscripts(over 250 pages) on "the category of manifolds" and "differential manifolds" for Bourbaki's famous textbook series.
He writes that it was submitted in the Bourbaki congress in 1957, but it was rejected by the Bourbaki members for they thought it too algebraic.

Is this true?
Does the manuscripts or the copy of it exist?

Comment: This sounds really interesting. You may want to ask this on Overflow. It is much more likely to be answered there. If you do end up posting there, do you mind pinging me with the link? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Why don't you ask it yourself? You can use the link to this question. My questions tend to be closed there for some reasons.

Answer (score 3):

It's true. Here is an account due to [Borel](http://www.ams.org/notices/199803/borel.pdf) (check page 6 (or 378 on the document's numeration))

There is a post about this on [Peter Woit's blog](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/wordpress/?p=2334)

And [here](http://archives-bourbaki.ahp-numerique.fr/) are the archives Bourbaki. (Note: I couldn't find these documents there)